# Entity Framework 7 Sqlite table creation script

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a small app using SQLite and EF7

```
class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

<..>

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mB) {
    mB.Entity<User>().HasAlternateKey(c => c.Name);
}
```

With `EnsureCreated()` I get the SQLite database and check creation code for table:

```
CREATE TABLE "User" ( "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_User" 
   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "Name" TEXT, CONSTRAINT "AK_User_Name" UNIQUE ("Name") )
```

How can I get this code using EF7?

Answer (score 0):

See issue [#2943](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2943). Until then, here is some code:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var services = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider)db).Instance;
    var model = services.GetService<IModel>();
    var differ = services.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();
    var generator = services.GetService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
    var sqlHelper = services.GetService<ISqlGenerationHelper>();

    var operations = differ.GetDifferences(null, model);
    var commands = generator.Generate(operations, model);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var command in commands)
    {
        builder
            .Append(command.CommandText)
            .AppendLine(sqlHelper.BatchTerminator);
    }

    // Here is the SQL.
    var sql = builder.ToString();
}
```